# How to rollback all `changeSet` inside `databaseChangeLog`, if one `changeSet` failed to apply?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, liquibase

I have configured the Liquibase and spring-boot using following properties:

- Spring-Boot

```
    spring:
      liquibase:
        change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml
        enabled: true
```

- db.changelog-master.yml

```
databaseChangeLog:
 - include:
      file: db/changelog/release-01/master.yml
 - include:
      file: db/changelog/release-02/master.yml
```

- release-02/master.yml

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: Prabal Srivastava
      logicalFilePath: release-02-01__t_user_table.sql
      context: User
      labels: InitialCommit
      comment: Initial changes for user table
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: 01__t_user_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
        - tagDatabase:
            tag: 0.0.2
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: rollback/01__t_user_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: Prabal Srivastava
      logicalFilePath: release-02-02__t_group_table.sql
      context: Entry
      labels: InitialCommit
      comment: Initial changes for group table
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: 02__t_group_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
        - tagDatabase:
            tag: 0.0.2
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: rollback/02__t_group_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

**Acceptance:** If any script failed to apply in `release-02` then all the `changeSet` in that `release-02/master.yml` should rollback.

**Currently:** If `02__t_group_table.sql` is falling then only group script is rolling back but user script is not rolling back.

I want the solution in such a way that, If staging environment application is upgrade to production environment and during Liquibase migration on production something fails then none of the `changeSet` in that  release should apply.

Comment: The default behaviour is recommended albeit if you really want, you need to update the rollback of change set 2 to include change set 1 rollback as well! Really not a recommended way but will get it done what you seek.

Comment: To avoid and still get what you want, keep 1 change set per file i.e. Split the change log file.

Comment: I partially agree with your solution. Problem in this solution is that, one  `changeSet` per release will make the file bulky.
 I am thinking to add the support in spring-boot in such a way that, if any migration fail than it will rollback all the changeSet related to that `deployment_id`

Comment: Yups, that another way to do it. 

Answer (score 0):

For your `release-02/master.yml` script, if you want to rollback all the changeSets in your changeLog "release-02/master.yaml, then I think you better off having just one changeSet (the first one) that includes the tagDatabase rollback tag you intend to rollback end point.  Then remove the other tagDatabase properties in the following changeSets that include the same tag.

Please consider the following example:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:  
      id: release-0.0.2 
      author: Prabal Srivastava  
      changes:  
        -  tagDatabase:  
             tag: 0.0.2
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: Prabal Srivastava
      logicalFilePath: release-02-01__t_user_table.sql
      context: User
      labels: InitialCommit
      comment: Initial changes for user table
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: 01__t_user_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: rollback/01__t_user_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: Prabal Srivastava
      logicalFilePath: release-02-02__t_group_table.sql
      context: Entry
      labels: InitialCommit
      comment: Initial changes for group table
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            path: 02__t_group_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
      rollback:
        - sqlFile:
            path: rollback/02__t_group_table.sql
            relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

To run a rollback on this changeLog you can simply run:
For Liquibase Maven plugin command:

```
mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=0.0.2
```

For Liquibase CLI command you can run:

```
liquibase rollback 0.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my problem is not related to `tagging`. 
`Tag` is working fine for me as expected. 
My problem is related to rollback.

Comment: The commands you provided for rollback, those are manual. I need to automate them.
That support is not there in `spring-boot-autoconfigure` jar.